# uploading a song n as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I was wondering if it would be possible to upload a song in as3, what i want to achieve is that people can push a button to load a song in and when theyve dont that, the title should display in a textfield. Then they would have the abbility to push a play button wich starts the song. would this be possible in as3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible. You can use FileReference class to let the user to select a song. and then load a song in Sound object and play sound object.

If you want to upload song on server, then you have to use either PHP/Java or AMFPHP/BlazeDS etc.

Comment: Yup as stated here, in order for the file to be saved on the server you'd need some sort of server side script to accept the upload, there's lots of examples out there to do this in PHP or Java or whatever (it's very easy in PHP and that's generally available on most linux or windows hosts) alternatively if you just want to make a desktop app you can use AS3 only and make it an AIR (adobe integrated runtime) app and save the files to disk

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly clarify? Would you like for people to load a song from their desktop into your application then play it or simply select a song and play it?

If effectively you 'd like for people to load their own song, then you can use the 
[FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class which basically will open a window which will allow the user to select an mp3 file and load it. Check the [browse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()) & [upload()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload()) method.

After the completed upload, you can use the [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) class to manipulate the loaded data. Provided the loaded file has id3 information, you should be able to retrieve the song title, artist etc... from the song id3 property.